# Is there an Alt-Tab like shortcut to switch monitor focus

Tags: multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts

I have multiple monitors at a Windows 10 workstation and it makes <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> somewhat confusing.  I often want to switch my focus to an application that's already visible on one of my monitors.  If I use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> it switches to the most recently used application which is not necessarily the one on the monitor I want.  Finding the application I want in the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> list is time consuming.  Is there a shortcut to just focus the window on top on a different monitor without using the mouse?  I rely heavily on keyboard shortcuts and avoid using my mouse.

NOTE: I'm aware that <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will separate applications by the monitor they're on, but it doesn't let me choose easily *with the keyboard*.

Comment: You mean other than just clicking it?

Comment: @Tetsujin - yes.  I rely heavily on keystrokes when I'm working and try to avoid my mouse.

Comment: Then you're asking your computer to be a mind reader, to know just exactly what you want without telling it.

Comment: What system are you on? From your note about CMD-TAB, I would guess you're using a Mac?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Windows, I just didn't know how to make the windows logo key in markdown

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry, I'll clarify the question

Comment: I usually write "Win+Tab" or "Winkey+Tab" when I can't actually enter the actual logo dingbat.

Answer (score 2):

From the list of shortcuts at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts, I don't think there's a shortcut to do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the same thing in 2023. Amazing. You can't leave your game full screen on monitor 1 and go work on monitor 2 via a focus switch.